# Maven surefire plugin suiteXmlFile parallel execution

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Is it possible to run parallel execution when there is a suiteXmlFile defined? I have my configuration as below. Also is there anyway we can if the test was executed parallelly in threads? Does it come up in log files?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>mytests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            <!--<suiteXmlFile>suites-test-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>-->
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have testng.xml, you can directly mention parallel attribute in testng.xml it self rt, if you have multiple testng files and you want to execute them in parallel, then you may use

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.20</version>
<configuration>
<forkCount>3</forkCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
<parallel>classes</parallel>
<threadCount>10</threadCount>
<suiteXmlFiles>
<suiteXmlFile>**/*-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
<!--<suiteXmlFile>suites-test-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>-->
</suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```